# jQuery AJAX removes Javascript on Phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, security, cordova

I'm writing an app using jQuery and Phonegap

On my javascript code I call $.ajax to request some of the app's sections to my web server. These sections are basically html snippets that I insert into the DOM. These snippets contain javascript code relevant to the section itself (which is dynamically built, thats why I don't include it on the app's main js file)

I'm calling these sections using this code:

```
//...
$.ajax(
            url,
            {
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(data){
                    $('#content').html(data);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    //...
                }
            });
//...
```

The data returning from the web server looks something like:

```
<div>...<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   //some code to be executed when this section loads
   //this is dynamically generated
});
</script>
```

Now, the problem is that when this code executes, it does not insert the SCRIPT tag into the DOM (only the html part).

This runs just fine on Chrome but when I test it on the emulator (using Ripple) does not.

I think it may be a security check but not sure on this.

My config.xml has this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" 
        version="0.1.1"
        versionCode="1"
        id="com.company.prod">  
    <name>...</name>
    <author>...</author>
    <description>...</description>



    <gap:splash src="splash.png" />

    <content src="index.html"/>
    <access uri="*" subdomains="true"/>

    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/battery"/> 
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/> 
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>

</widget>
```

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, this is because you cannot append or use innerHTML to insert script tags. I would suggest changing the location of this ajax call to the spot where the insertion will be made and then changing the line

```
$('#content').html(data);
```

to

```
document.write(data);
```